# Call function recursively without additional parameter

Tags: recursion, vbscript

I wrote vbscript function which search the list of free ports on Unix. So my code looks like this:

```
Function FindFreePorts(ByVal intPortToStart, ByVal intCountOfPortToSearch, ByVal arrFreePorts)
   Dim i, arrCommand, arrTmp, blnFindAllPort, j, strCommand
   Dim blnFree, intCountOfFreePorts

   strCommand = "lsof -i | awk '{print $8}' | sed -n '/"    
   For i = intPortToStart To intPortToStart+intCountOfPortToSearch - 1
       If i = intPortToStart+intCountOfPortToSearch - 1 Then
           strCommand = strCommand & ".*"& i & "$/s/.*://p'"
       Else
           strCommand = strCommand & ".*:" & i &"\|"
       End If     
   Next

   Push arrCommand, strCommand  
   arrTmp = Array() 
   arrTmp = ExecuteCommandOnUnix(arrCommand, Null, _
                                                                        Environment.Value("UNIXHOST_NAME"), _
                                                                        Environment.Value("UNIXHOST_USER"), _
                                                                        Environment.Value("UNIXHOST_PWD"))  
   ' Count of busy port is UBound(arrTmp) - the other ports are free
   ' Find free ports
   intCountOfFreePorts = intCountOfPortToSearch 
    For i = intPortToStart To intPortToStart+intCountOfPortToSearch - 1
        blnFree = True
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrTmp)
            If arrTmp(j) = CStr(i) Then
                blnFree = False
                j = UBound(arrTmp)
            End If
        Next
        If blnFree Then
            Push arrFreePorts, i
            intCountOfFreePorts = intCountOfFreePorts - 1
        End If
    Next
    '
   If  intCountOfFreePorts = 0 Then
       blnFindAllPort = True
   Else
        blnFindAllPort = False
   End If

   If Not blnFindAllPort Then
       ' We found UBound(arrFreePorts), we need to find intCountOfPortToSearch - UBound(arrFreePorts) 
       Do While intCountOfPortToSearch - UBound(arrFreePorts) - 1 <> 0
                arrFreePorts = FindFreePorts(intPortToStart + intCountOfPortToSearch + 1, intCountOfPortToSearch - UBound(arrFreePorts) - 1, arrFreePorts)
                If intCountOfPortToSearch - UBound(arrFreePorts) - 1 = 0 Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
       Loop
   End If

    FindFreePorts = arrFreePorts
End Function
```

As you can see I call this function recursively in `Do While` cycle. Everything works ok but I don't like arrFreePorts parameter here. So I should write this code to execute my function:

```
arrPort = FindFreePorts(intStartFromPort, intCountToSearch, arrPort)
```

But I have no idea how to rewrite this function without this parameter. Then I could call it in more simple way:

```
arrPort = FindFreePorts(intStartFromPort, intCountToSearch)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly, it looks like you're passing a _copy_ of your array with every function call. And since you're using recursion, that could be a lot of copies! Why not just declare an array in your calling scope (the scope that originally calls `FindFreePorts`) and pass that array, by reference, to `FindFreePorts`. Now you're just passing a reference to your array instead of a copy of it each time. And you don't have to return it so your `Function` can become a `Sub`. You'll still need your `Push` routine to grow the array dynamically, though.

Comment: Thanks, did as you told, everything works as expected but more faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep things (experiments, illustration of @Bond's contribution) simple, let's consider the task of putting the chars of a string into an array.

A function that shall return an array (without getting it via parameter or global) needs to create the array:

```
Function f1(s) ' default ByRef is ok, because Left and Mid return new (sub)strings
  If "" = s Then
     f1 = Array() ' return empty array for empty string
  Else
     Dim t : t = f1(Mid(s, 2)) ' recurse for tail - sorry no tail recursion
     f1 = cons(Left(s, 1), t) ' copy! result of cons to f1/function's return value
  End If
End Function
```

The growing of the array could be done inline, but for clarity I use a helper function [cons()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons):

```
Function cons(e, a) ' default ByRef is ok; neither e nor a are changed
  ReDim aTmp(UBound(a) + 1) ' create larger array
  Dim i : i = 0
  aTmp(i) = e ' 'new' head
  For i = 1 To UBound(aTmp)
      aTmp(i) = a(i - 1) ' copy 'old' elms
  Next
  cons = aTmp ' copy! aTmp to cons/function's return value
End Function
```

Calling the function is nice:

```
  WScript.Echo 3, "[" & Join(f1("12456789"), ",") & "]"
```

The price to pay for avoiding the passing of 'the' array:

1. a lot of copies (array assingment copies in VBScript)
2. no [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) (I doubt, however, that VBScript exploits it)
3. about factor 10 slower than the Sub approach ((c) Bond) below

As *in this case* the recursive calls can/should work on the 'same' array, a Sub does the task more efficiently (and is less complex):

```
Sub s1(s, a) ' default ByRef is ok; a should be modified, s isn't touched
  If "" <> s Then
     ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) + 1) ' grow! a
     a(UBound(a)) = Left(s, 1)
     s1 Mid(s, 2), a ' tail recursion for tail
  End If
End Sub
```

Calling it looks nasty:

```
  ReDim a(-1) : s1 "123456789", a : WScript.Echo 3, "[" & Join(a, ",") & "]"
```

But that can be avoided by a wrapper:

```
Function f2(s)
  ReDim aTmp(-1)
  s1 s, aTmp
  f2 = aTmp
End Function
```